# componentwillmount() Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm implementing get all image by type with redux-saga. I have 2 types, let's say, type kristik and type motif.
When I'm implementing type kristik, it got successful response, but when it comes to type motif, the response is error.

here my code that has the error in console

```
    componentWillMount() => {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;

        dispatch(getAllMotif());
    }
```

I got error in `dispatch(getAllMotif());` in `commponentWillMount()`

Here my `getAllMotif()` code

```
    getAllMotif(token) {
        const path = `motif`;
        const method = 'get';

        return request.process(method, path, null, token);
    },
```

Here my `sagas getAllMotif` code

```
export function* getAllMotif() {
    try {
        let { detail } = yield select(state => state.user);

        const result = yield call(API.getAllMotif, detail.api_token);
        yield put({
            type: types.GET_ALL_MOTIF_SUCCESS,
            payload: result,
        });
    } catch (err) {
        yield put(handleError(err));

        yield put({
            type: types.GET_ALL_MOTIF_FAILURE,
            payload: err,
        });
    }
}
```

here my reducer

```
            case types.GET_ALL_MOTIF_SUCCESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                motif: [
                    ...action.payload.data.data
                ]
            };
```

here my request code

```
internals.process = (method, path, payload, token, contentType=internals.contentType) => {
    const request = {
        url: `${API_URL}/${path}`,
        method: method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': contentType,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
        },
    };

    if (token) {
        request.params = {
            token: token,
        };
    }

    if (payload) {
        request.data = payload;
    }

    return axios.request(request)
        .then(res => {
            if (![200, 201].includes(res.status)) {
                throw new Error(res.status);
            }

            return res.data;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(method, path, error);
            return Promise.reject({
                message: error.response.data.error,
                code: error.response.status
            });
        });
};
```

I don't know why in this type get error, because in type kristik also have very similar code.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't dispatch an action that wasn't a plain object, your function `getAllMotif` not return a plain object. That lead to the error here.

You should dispatch an normal action

```
getAllMotifAction(token) {
    const path = `motif`;
    const method = 'get';

    return { type: 'GET_ALL_MOTIF', data: { path, method } };
},
```

Then in in saga, you catch this action and handle it with your saga function

```
takeLatest('GET_ALL_MOTIF', getAllMotif);
```

Comment: in `request.process()` have function to check token, and URL to request data

Comment: Could you update question with the content of that function? I don't know what function do or what it return

Comment: Function `process` perform async call that should done in saga function, also it return a `promise` object - not plain object

Comment: I don't know why error still come, but I think my code is already correct

Comment: @jhon I think you misunderstanding the difference between what redux-saga and redux try to archive. You are dispatching to redux store by using `dispatch(actionCreatorFunction())`, the `actionCreatorFunction` have to be return a plain object, like my funcion `getAllMotifAction` above, but the function `request.process` that you are using return a `promise` object, so the issue happen

Comment: and what should I do? seriously I'm stuck here from yesterday